# Transformar uma lista em um dicionário python usando arquivo

Tags: python, lista, dicionário

Estou juntando as informações de pastas e arquivos de um diretório específico de várias máquinas, e gostaria de futuramente ter como chave o caminho/nome_do_arquivo e ir juntando todos as máquinas que contém o mesmo arquivo assim "/tmp/exemplo" : "192.168.56.105", "192.168.56.106", ...

Para isso preciso mudar o formato do meu arquivo que encontra-se como uma lista de listas, para mudar para um dicionário

eu tenho um arquivo que lista as pastas e arquivos de um diretorio desta forma:

```
[['/tmp/javac', '192.168.56.105'], ['/tmp/java', '192.168.56.105'], ['/opt/.java', '192.168.56.105'], ['/opt/testejava', '192.168.56.105']]
```

e eu queria ler ele em python e transformá-lo assim:

```
{
    '/tmp/javac': '192.168.56.105', 
    '/tmp/java': '192.168.56.105', 
    '/opt/.java': '192.168.56.105',
    '/opt/testejava': '192.168.56.105'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A classe  `dict` do Python aceita um iterável de pares como entrada em que o primeiro valor do par será a chave e o segundo será o respectivo valor, então para obter o dicionário que deseja a partir da lista que possui basta fazer:

```py
data = [['/tmp/javac', '192.168.56.105'], ['/tmp/java', '192.168.56.105'], ['/opt/.java', '192.168.56.105'], ['/opt/testejava', '192.168.56.105']]

result = dict(data)
# {'/tmp/javac': '192.168.56.105', '/tmp/java': '192.168.56.105', '/opt/.java': '192.168.56.105', '/opt/testejava': '192.168.56.105'}
```

Answer (score -1):

Para transformar a lista de listas em um dicionário, você pode percorrer a lista original e adicionar cada par de valores como uma chave-valor ao dicionário. Você pode fazer isso usando um loop for e o método `dict()` para criar o dicionário final.

Veja o código abaixo que talvez possa resolver o seu problema:

```
# Lista original
original_list = [['/tmp/javac', '192.168.56.105'], ['/tmp/java', '192.168.56.105'], ['/opt/.java', '192.168.56.105'], ['/opt/testejava', '192.168.56.105']]

# Transformando a lista em um dicionário
final_dict = {}
for sublist in original_list:
    final_dict[sublist[0]] = sublist[1]

# Imprimindo o dicionário final
print(final_dict)
```

Este código cria um dicionário vazio chamado final_dict e, em seguida, percorre cada sublista da lista original. Para cada sublista, ele usa o primeiro elemento como a chave e o segundo elemento como o valor do dicionário. Finalmente, ele imprime o dicionário final.